# multiple must query on ElasticSeach with time range

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to use multiple must query but I get following error. Duplicate key "must" syntax error. When I add the range to the must block above, it doesn't give the correct result either.

What I want is briefly this: If both word1 and word2 are in the log, I want to capture them.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "word1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "word2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date_time": {
              "gte": "now-15m"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want word1 OR word2, not a AND I think ? so you should use `should` for the 2 `match` and `must` for the `range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try a query like this:

```
GET .yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "word1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "word2"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date_time": {
              "gte": "now-15hm"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```